Euler factors from bad primes and the Beilinson-Bloch vanishing conjecture
The vanishing part of the Beilinson-Bloch conjecture asserts that for a smooth projective variety $X$ over a number field $K$, $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}} \operatorname{CH}^i(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} = \operatorname{ord}_{s=i} L(H^{2i-1}(X_{\overline{K}}, \mathbb{Q}_\ell), s)$, where $\operatorname{CH}$ is the Chow group. I am wondering what exactly the $L$-function needs to be to make the conjecture plausible. I assumed that the $L$-function was supposed to be the Artin $L$-function on the Galois representation $H^{2i-1}(X_{\overline{K}}, \mathbb{Q}_\ell)$, plus factors at infinite primes. However I have seen related situations and special cases in the literature in which it suffices to consider the Euler product defining the Artin $L$-function only over good primes, i.e. finite places of $K$ where the inertia acts trivially. For instance this suffices in the special case $i = 1$. Does it suffice to consider the Euler product only over good primes for general $X$ and $i$? Is this at least conjecturally the case?
EDIT: I see that a conjecture due to Serre (stated as conjecture 5.45 in "Zeta functions of varieties and motives" by Bruno Kahn) implies that the Euler factors at bad primes are finite and nonzero at $s = i$. So I guess the question becomes whether you need to include the Euler factors from the infinite primes in the vanishing part of the Beilinson-Bloch conjecture.

For this version of the BB conjecture, it doesn't matter whether you include the Gamma factors at infinite primes or not, since they cannot vanish at s = i. (This is easy to see from the fact that $H^{2i-1}(X)$ is a pure motive of odd weight, cf the recipe for the Gamma factors in Deligne's "Valeurs de fonctions L et periodes d'integrales".)
